# Some packages not recognised by TexStudio

Tags: packages, miktex, installing, texstudio

Some of my packages are not recognised by TexStudio (examples: pdfpages, mathtools, ramsstyle and so on), but most of the packages I use are recognised.

I have installed all of these packages with MikTex 2.9 (even tried to reinstall them), but still TexStudio won't recognise them. This is getting tiresome since I really need to use pdfpages to include a PDF to my document.

Is there any way for me to check if the packages are installed, and if TexStudio is actually connected to MikTex? I also tried to install some new, random packages with MikTex but they were not recognised either.

I don't know if I checked the "Install on the fly" option when I installed MikTex (was and still are fresh in the Latex game).

Any help is much appriciated!

Comment: Are you after adding those packages refresh FNDB database?

Comment: What do you mean by "are not recognized"?

Comment: I mean the package is "Not found" when writing \usepackage{pdfpages}. 
I have been installing packages with the Package manager, but still they are not found by TexStudio. 

I will try to refresh FNDB database now.

Comment: Nothing changed after I refreshed the FNDB database.

Comment: open a command line (search for cmd in windows) and type `pdflatex --version` and `findtexmf article.cls` and `findtexmf pdfpages.sty`  (everytime hit enter at the end) and show a screenshot of the output.

Comment: Don't worry about *Not found* warnings. TeXstudio has not influence in the installed packages. I have a full TL installed and it shows that I don't have some package installed. But after compiling, no problem. **But** if the message comes from the compilation process (not only on the editor body) then probably you didn't install the package rightly.

Comment: See this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236225/24770

Comment: Here is an image of what I got, @UlrikeFischer: http://i.imgur.com/FCN0hN9.png?1

Comment: The package is there and your document should compile without problems. Obviously it is texstudio and not miktex/latex that complains about a missing package. @TimHoffmann: I don't have a multiuser installation and so can't test but I have some doubts that `mpm --list` lists the packages installed by the admin.

Comment: I restarted TexStudio and suddenly the package is not listed as "not found" anymore. 

The \includepdf[pages=-]{filename} didn't work, but somehow this worked:

\includepdf[pages=-]{fig/filename}

So my problems are solved for now, I guess. Thanks for the help everyone! :)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: It may be the case that `mpm --list` is not the whole truth. It would be correct to get the contents of the filename database (FNDB). However, as far as I know, there is no API to query MikTeX about this and the FNDB itself is a proprietary binary format and is thus not easily parsable. This is in contrast to TeXlive where we can easily parse the ls-R data files. So for MikTeX `mpm --list` is the best guess we can get.

Comment: @OlavS: The scan for installed packages is only performed once at startup of TXS. TXS does not recognize if you install a package while TXS is running.

Comment: @TimHoffmann: Do you know this: http://www.miktex.org/sdk

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for the hint. Formally, the SDK seems to be a good approach. However, the required functionality does not seem to be exposed. I've posted the question to the MikTeX mailing list.

Comment: @TimHoffmann Is there any news here? Maybe you can provide an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B no news. AFAICS this is currently not solvable.

Answer (score 1):

TeXstudio checks which packages are installed on startup. When you `\usepackage` one it didn't find, this is marked as "not found" (being underlined in green).

When you install a package after starting TeXstudio, either using MiKTeX's install-on-the-fly feature or manually through the package manager, TeXstudio does not know about this. It will still mark the now installed package as "not found".

However, you don't really have to care about this. MiKTeX does the actual compiling and knows which packages are installed. As long as your document compiles fine, it is inconsequential if TeXstudio knows about all the packages you use therein.

If it bothers you, just restart TeXstudio. It will redo the check and find the new package.