# Tasks Package (not found) Is there any alternative to that package?

Tags: packages, tasks

I would like to make horizontally aligned items with equations with `multicols` and `tasks` packages, but `multicols` doesn't align and texstudio doesn't recognize the `tasks` package (which I've already installed). Could anyone help me?

[image] [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is your distribution?

Comment: Need to use your package manager to verify why "not found" in either MiKTeX-console or TeX Live -gui the package should be verified as installed then at ALL user levels (admin if necessary) ensure the filename database is refreshed.

Comment: I do not know which distro (MiKTeX / Tex Live / W32tex) you use but most include one for package maintenance

Comment: I have the miktex 2.9 complete installed

Comment: I've already verifeid with the miktex console as admin and i'm sure that the database is all refreshed

Comment: When you installed If "only for me" you are able to simply run MiKTeX-console as single user then it is easier to go to package tab to uninstall reinstall one package but ensure you also use "tasks" update filename database so system reassesses what you did. If you have admin user aswell you need to repeat that task as admin user Probably do it as admin first

Comment: ok thanks a lot i'll try to do that

Comment: P.S. ensure you close editor first

Comment: I only can uinstall and reinstall as admin... what i do now ?

Comment: The fact that TexStudio does not find the package does not mean that it is not installed, as long as LaTeX itself (MiKTeX in this case) can find the package then you don't need to worry about the warning and you can just use the package and compile documents with this package. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246253/some-packages-not-recognised-by-texstudio or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236225/.

Comment: Nothing.. i give up but thanks a lot for you help!